# Rails 4 : What is cached when using config.cache_classes = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, caching

I was just wondering and didn't find explicit response on what in the model class (ActiveRecord) is cached when setting config.cache_classes to true ?

Could someone tell me or point me to the doc I didn't found ?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It determines whether or not your application classes are reloaded on each request. If it's true, you have to restart your server for code changes to take effect (i.e. you set it to true in production, false in development.)

Documentation is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration).

Comment: Note that the test value should probably be false too if your application uses spring (see [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-6-1-to-rails-7-0-spring))

Answer (score 0):

> What is cached when using `config.cache_classes = true`

It responsible for two thing in `rails 4`

**1.** It prevent class reloading between requests.

**2.** It ensure `Rack::Lock` in not included in `middleware stack`, so
    that your thread don't get locked.